# Error installing Zorin OS from boot menu

Tags: boot, installation, lenovo-desktop-computer, zorin

I managed to install Zorin OS (based on Ubuntu) successfully on my laptop and it works perfectly, however, I cannot install it on my work computer. It is a Lenovo Ideacenter AIO 510, all-in-one desktop computer.

When I reach the boot screen and choose *Install Zorin OS*, I get a black screen with the error message shown below, and the computer restarts.

```
[    0.018324] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, invalid threshold interrupt offset 1 for   
bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xd010000001000000)
[    0.072134] [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4: fe00000000070f0f    
[    0.072134] [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 100000 MISC d002000001000000  
[    0.072134] [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:670f00 TIME 1527621164 SOCKET  
0 ACPI 0 microcode 6006704
```

Tried one more step- disabling fast startup on windows. Did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue when installing zorin os (ubunto-based distro) on a old dual boot machine (hp dc5800) that already has windows 7 on it. the error appeared after booting into the usb with zorin os on it and clicking on install zorin, after that I would get a bsod that refer to an acpi memory handler issue that resulted in a kernel panic not syncing: Attempted to kill init! message and my system stalling.

I managed to resolve it by going in windows 7 and updating the bios to the latest version available on the computer's manufacturer's site. after the bios was updated, I was able get zorin os to boot and I was able to complete my dual boot installation.

Hope it helps!